# Drush or just cron custom feeds import?

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

I need to call a function (that includes using feeds) within my module periodically while minimizing site speed. I fetch data. Next I process all nodes in seperate feeds (in background). It can be called with a single function in my .module file. How should I optimize this? Someone advised me drush?

Answer (score 0):

you can have it fire when cron is run. use the module "poormanscron" and it can fire when someone visits your site at a specific time.